# Can GraphQL work without server implementation?

Tags: graphql

Right now I'm writing a React application.

For education purposes I'd like to write own todo application, using some REST API service to fetch data (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts for example)

Can I write a couple of GraphQL queries to get data from this server knowing that their backend implementation does not support GraphQL queries?

In other words, can I use GraphQL on client, and write own backend (or request to one above) as a simple REST API service?

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: Only if you count implementing a layer on the client side that intercepts GraphQL-style requests and handles conversion of the request to a REST-style one then of the response back to a GraphQL format.